# how to add new currency support to golang.org/x/text/currency

Tags: go

The package `golang.org/x/text/currency` is designed to handle currency standard printing implementation.

It provides all the most common currencies via a bunch of [const currency.Unit](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/currency#Unit)

A `currency.Unit` is a struct to an [uint index](https://github.com/golang/text/blob/master/currency/currency.go#L68)

They refers to some data located under `internal` [folder](https://github.com/golang/text/tree/master/internal).

I want to add support for a new currency. How do I proceed ?

Comment: You may need an Adapter or something.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/contribute.html

Comment: @MichaelHampton kind of true...

Answer (score 1):

Considering the Currency Unit represents [ISO_4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217), and seems fairly complete, you can't extend it directly.

You would need to go:

- either with a third-party package like [`Rhymond/go-money`](https://github.com/Rhymond/go-money), which could be more complete
- implement your own definition, as in [`thrasher-/gocryptotrader/currency`](https://github.com/thrasher-/gocryptotrader/tree/master/currency), where new currencies can be extended [through a json config file](https://github.com/thrasher-/gocryptotrader/blob/master/config_example.json).
  Or, as [mh-cbon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4466350/mh-cbon) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509632/how-to-add-new-currency-support-to-golang-org-x-text-currency/56547246#comment99685440_56547246), through a call within [`init()`](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init).

Comment: yes money package is a good alternative. I have added a call within init(). the json approach is overkill.